# Python Change Dataframe Value in Specific Column And Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe generated from unformatted csv. So I need format some datas (e.g there is some strings as 12.323,03 for float format and i'm trying to convert them 12323.03 for convert string to float in python)
I'm trying to do it as:

```
for column in data:
if(data[column].name != 'blabla' and data[column].name != 'otherblabla'):
    for row_value in data[column]:
        if type(row_value) == str:
            float_format = row_value.replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            row_value = row_value.replace(row_value, float_format)
```

float format: converts string "12.323,03" to "12323.03".
But row values are not affected. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

To affect the new value, you must locate it with

df.loc[row_index,column_name] = row_value

To do so, try an enumerate.

for row_index, row_value in enumerate(data_column):

Here an example to understand it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[5,6,7,8]})
print('Before change')
print(df)
for i,j in enumerate(df['B']):
    if j == 6:
        df.loc[i,'B'] = 4
print('Afetr Change')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `row_value` is a single value of a row/column pair in the original df which does not reference back that df position. As the other answer has pointed out with your approach you need to locate the value in order to change the df.

Additionally, I want to mention that the second `replace` of `row_value` could be substituted with simply `row_value = float_format`. Also, I share with you an approach using `apply` which I consider cleaner and you might find useful:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'c1': ['100,12', 1.230, '30.000,4'], 
        'c2': ['5.367,46', '10', 7.3],
        'c3': ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
)

cols = ['c1', 'c2']
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(
        lambda x: float(x.replace('.','').replace(',','.')) if type(x) == str else x
    )
```

This results in:

```
         c1       c2 c3
0    100.12  5367.46  a
1      1.23    10.00  b
2  30000.40     7.30  c

c1    float64
c2    float64
c3     object
dtype: object
```